# How can I make Javascript's reduce method work on arrays of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

## Orig Problem

I was working on an exercise that should sum up the amount of change left in a cash register, variable `cid`.

`cid` looks something like this:

```
var cid = [["PENNY", 0], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]];
```

In a case like this, when all of the **values** are 0, then I should report that the register is empty.

I thought something like this should work:

```
if (cid.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
  return prevVal[1] + curVal[1];
}) === 0)
```

But it didn't.

---

## Digging In

Some strange things seem to happen when working with arrays within arrays and the `reduce` method.  For instance:

```
cid.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
  return prevVal[1] + curVal[1];
});

NaN
```

Whereas, if I just let the entire array through, I do get something, albeit something strange:

```
cid.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
  return prevVal + curVal;
});

"PENNY,0NICKEL,0DIME,0QUARTER,0ONE,0FIVE,0TEN,0TWENTY,0ONE HUNDRED,0"
```

---

It's clear to me that, when using `reduce`, it **isn't simply delving one level deeper** into the array / object, as I had suspected it would.

However, the only other thing I might have suspected is also wrong:  **it's not delving into all the levels**, either.  If this were the case, I would have expected to have seen something like this (notice there are no commas):

```
"PENNY0NICKEL0DIME0QUARTER0ONE0FIVE0TEN0TWENTY0ONE HUNDRED0"
```

---

## Two Questions

1. Is there any way to effectively use the `reduce` method with multi-dimensional arrays like this?
2. Can anyone help me understand what is going on under the hood here?

Comment: `array + array === array.toString() + array.toString()`

Comment: The two answers below nailed it - just wanted to point out that you're actually returning the number of coins/notes you have, not their value.

Comment: So is that supposed to be `[[["PENNY", 0], "NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]` or `[["PENNY", 0], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]`

Comment: @jdphenix No, it isn't.  I made a typo, and have now fixed it.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're slightly misunderstanding the nature of `reduce`; the value in `prevVal` is not whatever value we were called with last; it's whatever value we *returned* last. Since you are returning an integer, `prevVal` is an integer, and `prevVal[1]` is `undefined`.

I'd suggest you alter your call to `reduce` to provide an explicit default of `0`, and rewrite your function to assume that `prevVal` is *always* going to be a number, not a value in your array.

```js
var cid = [
  ["PENNY", 0],
  ["NICKEL", 0],
  ["DIME", 0],
  ["QUARTER", 0],
  ["ONE", 0],
  ["FIVE", 0],
  ["TEN", 0],
  ["TWENTY", 0],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]
]

var val = cid.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
  return prevVal + curVal[1];
}, 0);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(val) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I did misunderstand that subtle aspect for what `prevVal` really represents within `reduce`.  The way you explained it is great, and that implementation of `reduce` makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work

```
cid.reduce( (memo, item) => memo + item[1], 0)
```

or

```
cid.reduce( function(memo, item) { return memo + item[1] }, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

No one explained to you what was happening 'under the hood' so I will take a shot at it.

So this is basically what is happening:

```
 cid.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
    return prevVal[1] + curVal[1];
 });

 NaN
```

In this case you are grabbing two arrays which javascript tries to coerce and it results in NaN

Here:

```
cid.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
   return prevVal + curVal;
});
```

It is reducing each element in each array but the return statement tries to reduce a string and a number. In js `0 + "string"` is 0string because js coerce the number to a string and then concatenates them.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused.  Near the end, you say `0 + "string"` is `0string`, which is exactly what I would have thought, but that is **not** what I saw.  Instead, it somehow coerced and created a **comma**.  That was the part which really confused me.  Also, I think I am grabbing two arrays in both attempts, it's just that the first attempt I further try to reduce to a single value.  @Hamms explanation still makes the most sense to me:  the `prevVal` becomes just an integer, since it is the **return**, whereas the `curVal` is still an array that must be subset.